# Splitting XML message into multiple messages with generic root and common header

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a beginner to XSLT and have spent sometime trying to figure out how to do the following transformation...

I want to divide an XML message that has one header and multiple items into multiple XML messages, where each message is having only one item element while the rest of the xml is the same.

So if we look at the following XML Input Message:

```
<RequestOne xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/myns/"    xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture"    xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/p">
<Header>
    <ID>AB1234</ID>
    <Number>61</Number>
</Header>

<Item>
    <Name>Item1</Name>
    <ItemID>I001</ItemID>
</Item>
<Item>
    <Name>Item2</Name>
    <ItemID>I002</ItemID>
</Item>
<Item>
    <Name>Item3</Name>
    <ItemID>I003</ItemID>
</Item>
</RequestOne>
```

I want to transform it to 3 messages having the same structure and elements, except that each message has one item of the original XML.

One important requirement is that the XSL code would be generic to any root element name and namespaces. That is, the request message's root can be `<RequestOne>, <RequestTwo> ... <RequestN>` and all its namespaces should be copied too.

I managed to create the following piece of code. I think it is missing copying the root element along with its namespaces.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='Item']"> 
    <!-- Missing here the part that would copy the root element along with the namespaces -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="../Item"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

If there is more than one way to do this, would it be possible to do it in only one template?

UPDATE:

Sorry for not providing the expected output. Here it is below

Message N:

```
<RequestN xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/myns/"  xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture"    xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/p">
    <Header>
        <ID>AB1234</ID>
        <Number>61</Number>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <Name>ItemN</Name>
        <ItemID>I00N</ItemID>
    </Item>
</RequestN>
```

Comment: What is the expected result of your example?

Comment: Easier to help you if you provied sample of the output you expect.

Comment: I added sample of the output messages. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am afraid that's still not quite clear. Do you want to output three separate XML documents? That's only possible with an XSLT 2.0 processor, or a processor that supports the  `<exsl:document>` extension element, such as libxslt.

Comment: Well, may be I should have mentioned that I will be sending each one through an HTTP request. I am developing this in a DataPower transform action, so basically I will be be building each message in a for-each iteration and build the message part inside a url-open body. 
I am sorry if I complicated this more and haven't been clear on this

Comment: Sorry, still not with you. If your input has 3 items and you want to have your output to have only one only, you need to tell the XSLT stylesheet which one.

Comment: That's right .. I did that using a for-each to loop over the Items, then passing one Item at a time to another template that builds the message with the one Item I sent as a parameter.
The reason why I am not concerned with output XML documents is because I won't use them in an output at all. I build these messages in an xsl for Datapower wrapped in `url-open` tags, which basically sends these formed messages through an HTTP request. So basically my code will be '<dp:url-open target="http://0.0.0.0:2232"><xsl:apply-templates select="_whatever_"/></dp:url-open>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood the question, you want to copy each `Item` in a separate `Request`, keeping the namespace of the `Request`, and omit the `Header`.

Following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Request')]">
     <xsl:for-each select="Item">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="message">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Request')]" mode="message">
  <xsl:param name="item"/>
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="$item"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to your input XML generates the ouput

```
<RequestOne xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/myns/" xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture" xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/p">
  <Item>
    <Name>Item1</Name>
    <ItemID>I001</ItemID>
  </Item>
</RequestOne>
<RequestOne xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/myns/" xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture" xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/p">
   <Item>
     <Name>Item2</Name>
     <ItemID>I002</ItemID>
   </Item>
 </RequestOne>
 <RequestOne xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/myns/" xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture" xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/p">
   <Item>
     <Name>Item3</Name>
     <ItemID>I003</ItemID>
   </Item>
</RequestOne>
```

Note that this output is not valid XML. Depending on the desired output which is not absolutely clear - possibly the splitted messages are only a part of a an unknown complete output - this could be changed to valid XML output by changing the first template to e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Request')]">
  <Requests>
     <xsl:for-each select="Item">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*" mode="message">
        <xsl:with-param name="item" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Requests>
</xsl:template>
```

in case the template would only be applied to a single Request.

In case of multiple Requests in the input XML the first XSLT above produces valid XML when the following template is added:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Requests>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[starts-with(name(),'Request')]"/>
  </Requests>
</xsl:template>
```

In case you want to keep the xml declaration in the output, just remove the attribute `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` from `xsl:output`.

**Update:** As the desired output was updated in the question - to have the `Header` in each splitted `Request`, this can be done with the following adjustment:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Request')]" mode="message">
<xsl:param name="item"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$item"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

`<xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>` just copies the `Header` in each splitted `Request`, as example only the first one of the three:

```
<RequestOne xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/myns/"
        xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture"
        xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/p">
  <Header>
    <ID>AB1234</ID>
    <Number>61</Number>
  </Header>
  <Item>
    <Name>Item1</Name>
    <ItemID>I001</ItemID>
  </Item>
</RequestOne>
```

Comment: It's quite possible that your interpretation of the question is the correct one. However, it needs to be said that the output here is not well-formed XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for mentioning. You mean because it's not wrapped in a root node element like e.g. `<Requests> .. </Requests>` ?

Comment: "*You mean because it's not wrapped in a root node element*" Yes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks, just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Would the following work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Item']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[local-name()='Header']/*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Header']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RequestOne xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/myns/" xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture" xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/p">
   <Item>
      <ID>AB1234</ID>
      <Number>61</Number>
      <Name>Item1</Name>
      <ItemID>I001</ItemID>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <ID>AB1234</ID>
      <Number>61</Number>
      <Name>Item2</Name>
      <ItemID>I002</ItemID>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <ID>AB1234</ID>
      <Number>61</Number>
      <Name>Item3</Name>
      <ItemID>I003</ItemID>
   </Item>
</RequestOne>
```

BTW, all the namespaces in your source XML are unused (and therefore redundant). If that's how your input will always be, you could simplify the stylesheet to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../Header/*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Header"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> If there is more than one way to do this, would it be possible to do
>   it in only one template?

Why would you care about that?

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help. I think I couldn't explain what I am trying to do thoroughly that I caused a confusion. Please check the update I added with the sample output.

Comment: You are right about that I should not care about using only one template. I had a misconception about using templates and that's why I thought it would be better if I used only one template. Thank you.